# Here i wanted to know how do i run a batch file (E:\Programfiles\bi\example.bat) from cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I tried running it by passing the exact path: `E:\Program files\bi\example.bat` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well it should work if you get the path right.

```
"E:\Program files\bi\example.bat"
```

`Program Files` has a space in it. That also means it needs to be wrapped in quotes.

Pressing *Ctrl + D/Ctrl + F* at the command prompt will autofill. This will make sure you have the right path. From Help (`cmd /?`).

> If completion is enabled with the /F:ON switch, the two control
>   characters used are Ctrl-D for directory name completion and Ctrl-F
>   for file name completion.  To disable a particular completion
>   character in the registry, use the value for space (0x20) as it is not
>   a valid control character.

Comment: You can also use tab for autocompletion for both paths and filenames

Comment: I agree with @SomethingDark. Using TAB works for me on both directories and files without `/F:ON`.

Comment: @lit Where is this documented? If it isn't its irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Paths should always be wrapped in double quotes `"` as each substring after a whitespace is seen as a new command, or switches for a command.

If you know the Path, simply enter wrapped by `"`

```
"E:\Program files\bi\example.bat"
```

Alternatively, the `example.bat` might have other switches which calls files in the directory it exists which will then be search for by the path you started `cmd.exe` from i.e. `C:\windows\system32` which will result in a batch file that starts up, but does not work as expected. You can therefore simply `cd` to the path and run it if successfully changed dir.

```
cd "E:\Program files\bi" && example.bat
```

The above can be easier achieve by using your <kbd>TAB</kbd> key simply by starting to type the relevant Directory and then <kbd>TAB</kbd> which will give you the predictions of directories that exists starting with the given name.

If for instance you are not sure where the file is and considering it is the only file by this name, you can simply search for it and execute if found.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /S /B /A-D example.bat') do set "variable=%a" & "%variable%"
```

The above line will search from the directory you run it from, but search all subfolders and once found, it will execute it. Note, should you want to run the above from a batch file, add another `%` to the variable `%a`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A-D example.bat') do set "variable=%%a" & "%variable%"
```